# Why is jax-rs still scanning all my packages even I declared certain package?

Tags: jax-rs, java-ee-8

```
<web-app>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>de.mycompany.dept.restapi</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/api/v2/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Even though I declare my url to be /api/v2/*  it is still possible to connect to all endpoints without this prefix . This is really annoying. So for example endpoint /employee can be connected

1. as I wrote in web.xml /api/v2/employee
2. /employee

I do not want second option. How can I prevent it. Thanks

Comment: Not enough to reproduce the problem. Please provide a [MRE]. Also what does the title have to do with the your problem in your question. Your title you're talking about Java packages and your question you're talking about URI paths.

Comment: my api should only be accesible via api/v2/...   !!!  But right now I have two options .  for example  localhost:8080/api/v2/employee or what I do not want localhost:8080/employee . Do you understand now ??

Comment: What does that have to do with the title of your post? Also we need a [MRE] to be able to reproduce the problem. Without that, we would only be making guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Different approach will work. Go to Servlet class and add "import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;". Enter your url path using "@WebServlet" annotation on the class. I leave an example below.

```
package net.usermanagement.web;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;// Look here
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;    
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;



@WebServlet("foo/baz")     // Look here
public class UserServlet extends HttpServlet {
.
.
.
```